# Dynamically generate a service file in openbmc

Tags: service, embedded-linux, systemd, openbmc

I need to implement the BIOS update functionality in the openbmc's phosphor-software-manager. In the following code snippet, versionId is a variable that can change dynamically. How can I dynamically generate a service file? or where will service file be generated?

```
void Activation::flashWriteHost()
{
    auto method = bus.new_method_call(SYSTEMD_BUSNAME, SYSTEMD_PATH,
                                      SYSTEMD_INTERFACE, "StartUnit");
    auto biosServiceFile = "obmc-flash-host-bios@" + versionId + ".service";
    method.append(biosServiceFile, "replace");
    try
    {
        auto reply = bus.call(method);
    }
    catch (const sdbusplus::exception_t& e)
    {
        error("Error in trying to upgrade Host Bios: {ERROR}", "ERROR", e);
        report<InternalFailure>();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is supposed to be a regular systemd service file - it's a text file that's reasonably well documented in systemd's man pages. The service files usually live in `/lib/systemd/system` folder, however that can change across systems in theory

Answer (score 0):

Systemd itself generates the unit in memory from the `obmc-flash-host-bios@.service` template unit. The value specified after the `@` (called the "instance name" in systemd) will be automatically substituted wherever the unit has a `%i` or `%I` expansion.

Compare with `getty@tty1.service`, which is automatically produced out of `getty@.service`.